# How to automatically enter the username in a popup window, ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have this code which gets a URL, however, the site requires a username to enter. This pops up as a pop-up window. - https://jsfiddle.net/221ztatv/

```
$.ajax({ 
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'http://www.reed.co.uk/api/1.0/search?keywords=imobilus%20jobs',
        data: { username: 'b110030d-7491-48fe-9354-05c0ec0181d7', password:'' },
```

However, I want it to automatically fill-in the username and password and submit it, is this possible?

Comment: Fill username and password from where? And you are using `GET`, never send passwords using `GET`

Comment: pop up comes in your fiddle ? not for me .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same techniques as outlined in [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5507234/how-to-use-basic-auth-and-jquery-and-ajax) on Stack Overflow can be used.

Either use jQuery's `username` and `password` attributes, or the below, with the `$.ajax`.

```
beforeSend: function(xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa(username + ":" + password));
};
```

Bearing in mind that username/password can be read by users. If site is already authenticated, or firewalled/secured internally, then that's better, or this can be for a reason - e.g., the API prohibit server-side authentication. Good luck.

Comment: where about do I place this?

Comment: Alongside the other `ajax` parameters:

Comment: $.ajax({ url: ..., beforeSend: ... })

Comment: its not working on chrome or morzila just safari mac, please help again!

Comment: $.ajax({ url...., username: "foo", password: "bar"}) no good either? How about proxying it server side instead?